# Printing records out in order using an array

Tags: cobol

I am wondering if what I want to do can be accomplished in COBOL. I am trying to read in hospital and patient data from a file that is not in order. Instead of using Sort (like everyone would in real life), I am to use an array to somehow sort the data that comes in. At the end I'm supposed to print out a report to another file grouped by hospital number.

So,

```
Hospital #
patient 018
patient 020

total for hospital #

Hospital #
patient 011
patient 009

total for hospital #
```

All of these hospital numbers is to be between 1 and 30 and patient numbers are between 1 and 20. I have a pretty good idea about what to do and how to sum up patient balances, but what do you think of going about it this way:

Read in data to an array (this would obviously be more than 1 dimension). At this point the data is unsorted in the array. I don't think it matters if it's sorted inside the array as long as it comes out on the report sorted. Does this sound right? And yes, this is for an assignment. Any tips or recommendations, feedback that could be offered without giving the answer?

EDIT:
Okay, so I tried to create a 2d type array that would have the fields I needed to get the job done (hos num, pat name, pat num, pat amnt). And of course I want to add each patient amount to a running total for hospital subtotal.

Here is my array:

```
01  HospArray value spaces.
       05  hosnum   occurs 30 times indexed by subsa.
         07  patnum   occurs 20 times indexed by subsb.
           10  patname  PIC X(20).
           10  patamt   PIC 9(7)v99.
         07  hossubtotal  PIC 9(7)v99.
```

While reading in the file and moving it to my working storage fields, I attempt to do two perform varying loops like this:

```
 perform varying subsa from 1 by 1 until subsa > 30
             move hos-num-ws to hosnum (subsa)
          perform varying subsb from 1 by 1 until subsb > 20

               move pat-name-ws to patname(subsa, subsb)
               move pat-amnt-od-ws to patamt(subsa, subsb)
               add  patamt(subsa, subsb) to hossubtotal (suba)

          end-perform
       end-perform
```

For some reason this won't compile and it gives the error of: Unexpected ADD and I am not sure why. I am using openCobol. I don't have a ton of experience so I'm not sure why this isn't compiling. I am still not sure if I am going in the right direction. I know I want to say, why the count is on a given hospital number move patient data to variables, and then somehow I should know when the current hospital number is done. Output the hospital subtotal, then repeat the process again.

Comment: You have to search the entire array for every record that you want to print out.  You're looking for the smallest record that hasn't been printed already.  So, you have to have some way of marking the records in the array as you print them.  You're basically doing a bubble sort without moving any of the array elements.

Comment: It would be good practice for you to try *all* the solutions: Cobol SORT, roll-your-own sort, insert-in-order and the simple subscripting. Although your example is somewhat contrived (doesn't take much to get a "patient number" above 20) the opportunity for the subscripting still comes up, either directly, or through "normalisation" of a value, or through "hashing" of some type.

Comment: In the ADD statement, you refer to "suba", which I imagine you have not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All of these hospital numbers is to be between 1 and 30 and patient numbers are between 1 and 20"

So use those values as "subscripts" into a table. Hopital number (1 to 30) for first level, patient number (1 to 20) for second. Everything set to, say, space beforehand.

When you come to list out, list hopitals which are not space (the value of the subscript at the time can tell you which, or instead store the hospital) and all their patients which are not space.

However, your sample output has patients "somewhat beyond" 1-20 :-)

EDIT:

There are several things wrong with your code.

When loading the table, you will just be adding one hospital/patient combination at a time.

When extracting the data from your table, you will be "looping" through it.

You move the hospital number to the table, but you are moving it to a group level, so will obliterate anything under that entry.

I've already mentioned the typo in a comment. When you get a compile message like that, you have to go with "well, something is wrong on or above this line".

You are doing your running total without having set the starting value to zero.

You don't need to do the running total as you go along, you can do it as you list out the data.

A couple of other things. You call your indexes "subsa" and "subsb". This is both not "meaningful" and confusing (they are indexes, subscripts are something slightly different).

You should be consistent with abbreviations. You should work at getting meaningful data-names.

Here's some example snippets. I've put *some* time into naming and formatting. You may think that this seems like a lot of effort, but that's what being capable with your editor is about. I didn't type any of the long names more than once, but I bet you typed out each of your short ones.

```
   01  HospArray value spaces.
       05  FILLER occurs 30 times 
                      indexed by I-Hospital-Entry.
           10  HA-Hospital-Entry.
               15  HA-Hospital-Number      pic xx. 
                   88  HA-hospital-not-present
                                           VALUE SPACE.
               15  FILLER occurs 20 times
                          indexed by I-Patient-Entry.
                   20  HA-Patient-Entry.
                       25  HA-Patient-Number         pic xx.
                           88  HA-Patient-not-present
                                           VALUE SPACE.
                       25  HA-Patient-Name           PIC X(20).
                       25  HA-Patient-Payment-Amount PIC 9(7)v99.
   01  Hospital-Sub-Total                            PIC 9(7)v99.
   01  W-Patient-Name                                pic x(20).
   01  Patient-Payment-Amount                        pic 9(7)v99.
   01  Hospital-Number.
       05  Hospital-Number-N                         pic 99.
   01  Patient-Number.
       ...
       SET I-Hospital-Entry         TO Hospital-Number-N
       SET I-Patient-Entry          TO Patient-Number-N 
       MOVE Hospital-Number         TO HA-Hospital-Number 
                                        ( I-Hospital-Entry )
       MOVE Patient-Number          TO HA-Patient-Number 
                                        ( I-Hospital-Entry 
                                           I-Patient-Entry )
       MOVE W-Patient-Name          TO HA-Patient-Name
                                        ( I-Hospital-Entry 
                                           I-Patient-Entry )
       MOVE Patient-Payment-Amount  TO HA-Patient-Payment-Amount
                                        ( I-Hospital-Entry 
                                           I-Patient-Entry )
       ...
       to output the results
       PERFORM                      LIST-PATIENTS-BY-HOSPITAL

       GOBACK
       .
   LIST-PATIENTS-BY-HOSPITAL.

       perform 
         varying I-Hospital-Entry 
           from 1 by 1 
           until I-Hospital-Entry > 30
           IF HA-hospital-not-present ( I-Hospital-Entry ) 
               CONTINUE
           ELSE
               PERFORM              LIST-PATIENTS
               DISPLAY Hospital-Sub-Total
           END-IF
           move HA-Hospital-Number 
                 ( I-Hospital-Entry ) 
                                    TO Hospital-Number
       end-perform
       .
   LIST-PATIENTS.
       perform 
         varying I-Patient-Entry 
           from 1 by 1 
           until I-Patient-Entry > 20
           IF HA-hospital-not-present ( I-Hospital-Entry ) 
               CONTINUE
           ELSE
               PERFORM              PATIENT-DETAILS
           END-IF
           DISPLAY Hospital-Sub-Total
       end-perform
       .
   PATIENT-DETAILS.
       move HA-Patient-Name 
             ( I-Hospital-Entry 
                I-Patient-Entry )   TO W-Patient-Name 
       move HA-Patient-Payment-Amount
             ( I-Hospital-Entry 
                I-Patient-Entry )   TO Patient-Payment-Amount 
       add Patient-Payment-Amount   TO Hospital-Sub-Total
       the "target" fields here can be in a formatted line for printing/DISPLAYing.
       .
```

Comment: Yes, this was a little mistake on my part. In reality the patient numbers would be between 1 and 20. I will try what you said and report back. I think I'm getting confused about the differences between arrays and tables. The assignment said to use an array. In the previous separate part of this same assignment I loaded a file into a table and searched for a certain value. That was kind of easy compared to this.

Comment: Wow, I see what you mean. Thank you very much for all of your suggestions. Also, I think it was pretty late at night and I was fried when trying to find the ADD error. I will take all of your advice to heart since it looks like you definitely know what you're talking about. I also think I need to review how to use tables/arrays in different situations. Again THANK YOU for your effort and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

The example patient numbers you gave are way out of the 1 to 20 range. I'm guessing that
you really meant to say there are between 1 and 20 patients per hospital, not that the patient numbers
fall into the range of 1 through 20.

I am also thinking that your statement: "somehow sort the data that comes in" is the real objective here.

The data from the input file are not sorted but you need to get them sorted. There are a few ways
of doing this:

- Read all the data into a table, then sort the table using an external SORT program or an internal
    sort you write yourself (e.g. bubble sort or something like that). Going this route would involve
    doing two sorts, one for each dimension of the table (eg. Sort by hospital and then by patient within hospital)
- Read a record and add it into the table such that the table is always sorted. This means being able to insert
    a new item at the top of the table, between two existing items in the table or at the end of the table.
    Again, this would be a two dimensional process: Add hospital, add patient within hospital
- The approach suggested by Bill Woodger would work well only if the hospital and patient numbers fall within
  a very small range (as you suggested they might).

At any rate you now have three suggestions to follow up on. Since this is a homework assignment I would base
my choice on what course material was being taught around this assignment. If internal/external sorting was
emphasized, then go the sorting route. If multi dimensional table declaration and manipulation were
recent topics then got with the build and keep the table sorted. If hashing came up then consider Bill's
suggestion.